# Why Split(new char['\\']) not work as what I think

Tags: c#

Don't know why case 2 can't `Split` the `str` to `a` and `b`

```
string str = @"a\b";

var result = str.Split('\\'); // work (case 1)

//var result = str.Split(new char['\\']); not work as what I want and will print a\b (case 2)

foreach (var r in result)
    Console.WriteLine(r);
```

Comment: I think you should have changed the narrative but not the cases - because now it's going to make it doubly difficult to know which answers are referring to case 1 (old) vs case 1 (new) vs case 2 (old) vs case 2 (new). In general, don't make edits that *invalidate* answers.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever How about now?

Comment: Well, it's too late now, but bear it in mind in the future - if you've numbered some cases, don't swap the numbers around later. By all means change your *narrative* about them if you've gotten that confused, or change the labels on which ones work or don't work. As I say, it can make it very confusing to read answers if they've started using your numbering scheme if we don't know which *version* of your numbering scheme they're referring to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`new char['\\']` is an array of characters of size 92. This is due to the implicit conversion from `char` to `int`:

```
int number = '\\'; // number is 92
char[] array = new char['\\']; // char array of size 92 with default values
```

This is as if you wrote:

```
var result = str.Split(new char[92]);
```

An array of single Character is written like this:

```
var result = str.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
```

Comment: "Empty" is not the right word for it... but default initialized would be better.

Comment: @JeffMercado I hesitated before writing that word. I know each element is the default of the type. mm I'll fix that .

Answer (score 3):

This is because `new char['\\']` creates an array of chars of `(int)'\\'` length. If you want an array with a given value, you can do `new char[] { '\\' }` or even `new[] { '\\' }` if you believe it's readable enough

Comment: "option 1 does not work and option 1 does" - might want to re-write that bit to make (some) sense.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are right, but this is not relevant anymore, as OP changed the question

Comment: @MichaelMao no problem for me, edits work both ways :)

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
string str = @"a\b";

String[] result = str.Split('\\'); // work (case 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`new char[]` is an array. Use

```
var result = str.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
```